# find average within select for a list of items

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to find the average price and then output cars with less than the average price for each model.Please can someone help me I am really struggling. my main table `carversions` contains the main details.

I have successfully got the data for one model of a car less than the average price but how do i do for multiple models (potentially without hardcoding)? Here is the query i used for one model

```
SELECT
    carversion.DateAdded,
    article.id 'ArticleId',
    carversion.VERSION 'Version',
    Article.DaysOld,
    carmake.name 'Make',
    carmodel.name 'Model',
    carversion.YEAR 'Year',
    carversion.Mileage,
    ('£' + LTRIM(STR(carversion.Price))) AS 'Price',
    carversion.FuelType,
    carversion.SellerType,
    carversion.Title,
    carversion.Description,
    carversion.Location,
    Article.Link,
    article.Thumbnail
FROM
    carversion
    JOIN Article ON Article.Id = carversion.ArticleId
    JOIN carmodel ON carmodel.id = article.CarModelId
    JOIN carmake ON carmake.id = carmodel.carmakeid
WHERE
    carmodel.name = 'a4'
    AND mileage < 60000
    AND price < (
        SELECT
            AVG(av.Price) AS 'Avg Price'
        FROM
            carversion av
            JOIN Article a ON a.Id = av.ArticleId
            JOIN carmodel mo ON mo.id = a.CarModelId
            JOIN carmake ma ON ma.id = mo.carmakeid
        WHERE
            mo.name = 'a4'
            AND mileage < 60000
    )
ORDER BY
    Article.daysold ASC,
    carversion.dateadded DESC,
    carversion.YEAR DESC,
    carversion.Price ASC,
    carversion.mileage ASC,
    carversion.VERSION DESC;
```

Please can someone help me do multiple models. as you can see i've just done one in the 'a4' model but how can i do multiple?

Car Make Table

```
Make_ID|Name
    1  Audi
    2 BMW
    3 Vauxhall
```

Car Model table

```
    ID|Name|Make_ID
    1  A4        1
    2 320si     2
    3 Astra     3
```

Thanks

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
WITH Car_CTE (DateAdded, ArticleId, Version, DaysOld,Make,Model, [Year],Mileage, Price,
                FuelType, SellerType,Title, Description, Location, Link, Thumbnail )  
AS  
(  

   SELECT
    carversion.DateAdded,
    article.id 'ArticleId',
    carversion.VERSION 'Version',
    Article.DaysOld,
    carmake.name 'Make',
    carmodel.name 'Model',
    carversion.YEAR 'Year',
    carversion.Mileage,
    ('£' + LTRIM(STR(carversion.Price))) AS 'Price',
    carversion.FuelType,
    carversion.SellerType,
    carversion.Title,
    carversion.Description,
    carversion.Location,
    Article.Link,
    article.Thumbnail
FROM
    carversion
    JOIN Article ON Article.Id = carversion.ArticleId
    JOIN carmodel ON carmodel.id = article.CarModelId
    JOIN carmake ON carmake.id = carmodel.carmakeid
WHERE

    AND mileage < 60000
) ,
AveData AS(

        SELECT
            Model,
            AVG(Price) AS 'AvgPrice'
        FROM Car_CTE
        GROUP BY Model
) 

SELECT
    ct.*
FROM Car_CTE  AS ct INNER JOIN AveData  AS ad ON ad.Model= ct.Model
WHERE ct.Price < ad.AvgPrice
```

Comment: i havent used CTE before so excuse me if this is a stupid question. But it doesnt complie, it complains about `1 AS Mdata    )` and also about the , before `AveData AS(`

Comment: Ok. try the new one.

Comment: nearly there.. now it complains about name just before the `AVG(Price) AS 'AvgPrice'` i tried carmodel.name but then it complains saying the multi-part identifier could not be bound?

Comment: I guess it is "Model" . not "name".

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something along these lines

```
SELECT  *
FROM carversion
JOIN Article ON Article.Id = carversion.ArticleId
JOIN carmodel ON carmodel.id = article.CarModelId
JOIN carmake ON carmake.id = carmodel.carmakeid 
JOIN
(
    SELECT  mo.name, 
            AVG(av.Price) AS AvgPrice
    FROM carversion av
    JOIN Article a ON a.Id = av.ArticleId
    JOIN carmodel mo ON mo.id = a.CarModelId
    JOIN carmake ma ON ma.id = mo.carmakeid
    WHERE mileage < 60000
    GROUP BY mo.name
) t ON carmodel.name = t.name and
       carversion.price < t.AvgPrice 
WHERE mileage < 60000
```

Using CTE you can avoid code duplication

```
WITH CTEcars AS
(
    SELECT  * -- here you may need to list your columns explicitely, since there can be duplicit names
    FROM carversion
    JOIN Article ON Article.Id = carversion.ArticleId
    JOIN carmodel ON carmodel.id = article.CarModelId
    JOIN carmake ON carmake.id = carmodel.carmakeid     
    WHERE mileage < 60000
)
SELECT  *
FROM CTEcars c
JOIN
(
    SELECT name, AVG(price) AS AvgPrice
    FROM CTEcars
    GROUP BY mo.name
) t ON c.name = t.name and
       c.price < t.AvgPrice
```

Comment: i dont think the above is correct because it now displays 7 rows for my A4 result when actually there is meant to be 2. and 75% of my dataset is returned from this query

Comment: thanks.. this is looks correct. if i add more filters for example fuel_type='petrol' do i also need to add this in the inside select as well as outside the select?

Comment: @sqlnoob exactly, or you can use CTE to avoid duplication of code

Comment: great makes sense.. yes it gives me the right result but you're right we have to duplicate for every filter.. Thanks for the assistance